# General Tire Altimax

Tags: tires

I just got some new General Tire Altimax tires and they are feeling a bit funny, like there are a thousand micro vibrations --- you can't quite feel them, but I'm worried maybe after a while, it would add up to more of a jarring sensation?

I had some Goodyear tires before (sorry -- didn't get the model number).

Comment: Does your new tires have the form nobbies on them (the small hair like pieces of rubber sticking out which are caused when forming the tire ... it's caused from the injection molding)? These may be what's causing the small vibrations and will disappear when the tires get broken in. Also, most tire places have a *so many day* ride warranty. If you don't like how they feel, take them back.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking the car back to the shop that did the tire change. They will be able to check the tire balance. If you are still not happy with the tire, most tire shops will allow you to exchange them within X number of days if you have not put more than ~100 miles on them (varies by shop).